# Variable(count_server) is not equal to the value it was in starting

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, ftp

I want to implement a code that adds some weight while requesting file, and the added weight should be subtracted when the file is downloaded over FTP.

I know I've mistaken in logic but couldn't find out.

What is happening now is, some amount is left in count_server1/count_server2/count-server3, that it doesn't reach 0 in the end.

Means the actual weight which it was assigned is not subtracted. and that's why some value is left in those variables.

I am using those variable values to set progress-bars.

Comment if you don't get my question.

```
protected void start_download()
{
    //Other actions
    for (int i = 1; i <= filecount; i++)
    {
        balance_load(filename, trnsfrpth);
    }
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            e1.Style.Add("width", count_server1 + "%");
            e1.InnerHtml = count_server1.ToString();
            e2.Style.Add("width", count_server2 + "%");
            e2.InnerHtml = count_server2.ToString();
            e3.Style.Add("width", count_server3 + "%");
        }

int weight;
public void count_weight()
{
    if (extension == ".jpeg" || extension == ".bmp" || extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".gif" || extension == ".png")
    {
        weight = 1;
    }
    if (extension == ".mp3")
    {
        weight = 5;
    }
    if (extension == ".mp4" || extension == ".avi" || extension == ".mov" || extension == ".mkv" || extension == ".wmv" || extension == ".flv")
    {
        weight = ((int)filesize / 2);
    }
}

int P;
public void balance_load(string filename, string trnsfrpth)
{
    count_weight();
    P = weight;

    if ((count_server1 <= count_server2) && (count_server1 <= count_server3))
    {
        //FTP request creation and providing credentials
        count_server1 += P;
        ftpClient_s1.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted_s1();
        ftpClient_s1.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(path), trnsfrpth);
    }
    else if (count_server2 <= count_server1 && count_server2 <= count_server3)
    {
        //FTP request creation and providing credentials
        count_server2 += P;
        ftpClient_s2.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted_s2();
        ftpClient_s2.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(path), trnsfrpth);
    }
    else if (count_server3 <= count_server1 && count_server3 <= count_server2)
    {
        //FTP request creation and providing credentials
        count_server3 += P;
        ftpClient_s3.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted_s3();
        ftpClient_s3.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(path), trnsfrpth);
    }
    else
    {}
}

public AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted_s1()
{
    Action<object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> action = (sender, e) =>
    {
        count_server1 -= P;
    };
    return new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(action);
}

public AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted_s2()
{
    Action<object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> action = (sender, e) =>
    {
        count_server2 -= P;
    };
    return new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(action);
}

public AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted_s3()
{
    Action<object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> action = (sender, e) =>
    {
        count_server3 -= P;
    };
    return new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution.

Rather assigning value and using it directly in the "Action", one can assign the value first and can use it later. As the problem might be with the value overriding.

So,
rather than this

```
public AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted_s1()
{
    Action<object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> action = (sender, e) =>
    {
        count_server1 -= P;
    };
    return new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(action);
}
```

I changed code to this :

```
public AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted_s1()
{
    int P_temp=P;
    Action<object, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> action = (sender, e) =>
    {
        count_server1 -= P_temp;
    };
    return new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(action);
}
```

Same thing for

```
AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted_s2()
AsyncCompletedEventHandler DownloadFileCompleted_s3()
```